# PyCharm 2.0 missing subdirectories

Tags: pycharm

I'm missing subdirectories of my project in PyCharm 2.0, what can I do to get them back?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such problem can be caused by incorrect conversion of the project format, in case you've used EAP/beta versions. Check the `.idea/modules.xml` file contents. You may need to delete the `.idea` directory and set up the project from scratch to resolve it.

Comment: Yeah I think something went amiss when I accidentally ran 1.5 and then switched back to 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

The folders may be excluded from your project. Try looking under `Preferences > Project Structure (in Project Settings)`.